# How to fix read-only error when adding host in Docker?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, host

I'm trying to add a host to `/etc/hosts` in a Docker image. I have the following line in my Dockerfile:

```
RUN echo 10.162.34.15 my-host-name >> /etc/hosts
```

When I run `docker build`, I get the following error:

```
#8 0.624 /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /etc/hosts: Read-only file system
```

I've found various old questions from prior versions of Docker where `/etc/hosts` was read-only, but nothing relevant to why this would be happening in a later version. I'm using Docker Desktop for Mac 3.3.3, Docker engine 20.10.6.

I'm aware of `docker run --add-host` and `extra_hosts` in `docker-compose`. I'm willing to use one of these instead, but I'd like to at least understand the source of this error.

Comment: The fundamental networking setup hasn't changed, and you can't provide this file in your image.  (It's better to avoid needing to change `/etc/hosts` at all if you can; set up a DNS server to provide host name to IP address mappings instead.)

Answer (score 6):

From the [docker docs page on /etc/hosts](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#managing-etchosts), they say docker itself may update the file.

> Since Docker may live update the container’s /etc/hosts file, there may be situations when processes inside the container can end up reading an empty or incomplete /etc/hosts file. In most cases, retrying the read again should fix the problem.

So because docker may rewrite the file, any changes you make from inside the image/container would be lost. To prevent this, they don't let you change it at all, so you get the read-only FS error.

Comment: The solution is to add --add-host parameter when building the docker image.
Example: `docker build -t yourtag --add-host=yourdomainname:10.X.X.X .`