# Modify /etc/hosts in Docker build

Tags: docker, nginx

I know Docker doesn't want us editing the /etc/hosts file

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#managing-etchosts
- [How to fix read-only error when adding host in Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69168860/how-to-fix-read-only-error-when-adding-host-in-docker)

However I still really want to.  Or something very close to it anyway.  I have an nginx reverse proxy running as a Docker container.  As part of that ***build*** process, I want to run `nginx -t` to test the validity of the nginx.conf file.  Unfortunately, the conf file refers to hosts (e.g. `rest-service`) that will only exist at run time (as part of a Docker Swarm or Kubernetes DNS resolution).

So I figured I could do something like:

```
RUN cp -f /etc/hosts /etc/hosts.bak && \
    echo "127.0.0.1 rest-service" >> /etc/hosts && \
    nginx -t && \
    cp -f /etc/hosts.bak /etc/hosts
```

Basically backup the nginx.conf file, create a temporary one that will just resolve to localhost, run the nginx test, and then copy the real one back in place.  Unfortunately, that gives the somewhat predictable error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: cannot create /etc/hosts: Read-only file system
```

Any clever ideas on how to validate the nginx.conf file during the build process?

Comment: Why not use `docker-compose` or use a test namespace in a kubernetes cluster to test the configuration?

Comment: Because I want to test during the BUILD stage, not once it's up and running.  No sense in building and launching containers if the conf file is invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never mind...  I didn't think the `--add-host` parameter would work for the `build` command, or if it did that the host modification would bake into the image.  Turns out it works fine for my purpose:

```
docker build -t ... --add-host rest-service:127.0.0.1 ...
```

And on an instantiated container, no trace of the addition.